# Injection into Jersey resource, HK2 doing injection instead of Weld when running in Java SE -> Unsatisfied dependency

Tags: junit, jersey-2.0, hk2, weld2

I have a simple test-application which I deploy to GlassFish (just one resource having one simple
class injected). On GlassFish everything is working fine (except for the exceptions when logging FINE, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775815/jax-rs-resource-error-couldnt-find-jax-b-element-for-class-java-lang-string-an)). I can successfully call the resource and Weld CDI is doing the injection.

Now when I start the application in Java SE to do a unit test with JUnit, it seems that HK2 is attempting to provide the injection, which then leads to a UnsatisfiedDependencyException.

I can define an AbtractBinder which will bind the InjectMe class so HK2 knows about it. Then the injection works fine. But Weld CDI should inject the class into the Jersey resource, not HK2.

The bootstrapping is done by creating a custom JUnit runner (WeldJUnit4Runner) and the `@RunWith(WeldJUnit4Runner.class)` annotation, for an example see here: http://blog.rocketscience.io/dependency-injection-with-cdi-in-java-se/

Weld CDI is bootstrapped successfully for the Java SE environment and I can successfully inject the InjectMe class into the actual JUnit test-class, just not into a Jersey resource. The InjectMe class is discovered by the Weld bootstrapping:

```
2014-07-16 10:41:12,730 [DEBUG] org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap - WELD-000106: Bean: Managed Bean [class com.test.rest.InjectMe] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
```

**Question: Why is HK2 attempting to inject the InjectMe class and not Weld when running in Java SE?**

**Edit:**
I created a Netbeans project, so you can reproduce this test easily:
[simple-service.zip](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/453583/simple-service.zip).
Don't forget to set the property for the java logging to a logging.properties file:

```
java.util.logging.config.file=C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\logging.properties
```

I've done that by defining it for the Netbeans "test file" action. In the property file, the following flag must be defined:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.level=FINEST
```

When I was testing yesterday, there was a time when this exact setup actually worked, without giving me those exceptions. I assume, there is a problem with static initialization, where HK2 sometimes is initialized first, which I think will lead to this error.

Resource:

```java
package com.test.rest;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Path("rest/import")
public class DataImport {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Inject
    private InjectMe me;

    public DataImport() {}

    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getHtml() {
        logger.debug("getHtml of DataImport called!");
        return "<html><body><h1>IMPORT Resource: " + me.field + " </body></h1></html>";
    }
}
```

ApplicationConfig:

```java
package com.test.rest;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.RolesAllowedDynamicFeature;

@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public ApplicationConfig() {
        register(DataImport.class);
        register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);

        //tracing/logging
        property("jersey.config.server.tracing.type", "ALL"); //enable tracing support, logs requests
        registerInstances(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getLogger(ApplicationConfig.class.getName()), true));
    }
}
```

POM:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test-service</name>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
           <version>2.2.1.Final</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>  
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin> 
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>2.3</version> 
                <configuration> 
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml> 
                </configuration> 
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.8</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Exceptions:

```
Jul 16, 2014 10:41:13 AM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder mapException
FINER: Starting mapping of the exception.
MultiException stack 1 of 3
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at Injectee(requiredType=InjectMe,parent=DataImport,qualifiers={}),position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,14097384)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:74)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:232)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:255)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:414)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:160)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2445)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:621)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1023)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:364)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
MultiException stack 2 of 3
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.test.rest.DataImport errors were found
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:267)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:414)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:160)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2445)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:621)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1023)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:364)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
MultiException stack 3 of 3
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.test.rest.DataImport
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:443)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:160)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2445)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:621)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1023)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:364)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Injected class:

```java
package com.test.rest;

public class InjectMe {
    public int field;
    public InjectMe()
    {
        field = 666;
    }
}
```

I am using: Glassfish 4.0 (build 89) (Java EE 7 Web)/NetBeans 8.0/maven 3.2.1/JDK 1.7/Weld 2.2.1

Comment: Can anybody at least reproduce the problem I have? I added a Netbeans project now, for easy testing.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding jersey glassfish cdi bridge:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-gf-cdi</artifactId>
  <version>2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: To make this a full answer, please elaborate. Why does the above solve askers question?